# Parse the JSON text from DB column nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have value in a column which stores the data as an json object .

Below is an example how the value is stored, I know the name of which I have to get the value over here

```
{"Name":"Today Date","value":"02/23/2017"},{"Name":"Exp Date","value":"02/23/2016"}
```

> I want the value of name "Today Date" over here.

I can't use json parse as we are still using sql server 2014.

> Currently with a hint from r41n's answer, I did the below:

```
select SUBSTRING
( '{"Name":"Today Date","value":"02/23/2017"},{"Name":"Exp Date","value":"02/23/2016"}',

PATINDEX('%{"Name":"Today Date","value":"%', '{"Name":"Today Date","value":"02/23/2017"},{"Name":"Exp Date","value":"02/23/2016"}') + len ('{"Name":"Today Date","value":"'),
 10)
```

If there are any other alternative solutions, please let me know.

Comment: SQL Server string functions are not well suited for parsing tasks, so the question is whether you have the option to use a CLR function for that? Otherwise you might use this: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: no i don't need CLR function over here , any way i can get it via split or substring

Comment: Sure, see the link I posted, which does exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### PATINDEX + SUBSTRING

It's slow and kinda ugly, but you could go and use [PATINDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) like so:

```
PATINDEX('%{"Name":"Today Date","value":"%', JSONColumn)
```

This would give you the starting-position in `JSONColumn` where string starts. You could then go and use `SUBSTRING(JSONColumn, 30, 10)` to get only the date.

*This obviously doesn't work if the date or JSON data is not constant or changes from one instance to another.*

I didn't test this, but used it before.